# Can't display proper time on chart.js timeline

Tags: javascript, jquery, date, charts, chart.js

I'm trying to create chart using `Chart.js` library. The X axis must be a timeline with this kind of time format: `DD-MM-YYYY HH:MM:SS`, but on the chart it gives incorrect dates and even my data does not display properly. If I remove `HH:MM:SS` part, the rest works fine. What's the problem? How can I display time in `DD-MM-YYYY HH:MM:SS` fromat?

Here is my fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/vaxobasilidze/ak1vmj9q/

```js
function factorData(data) {
  let _data = data.map((e, i, a) => {
    let prev = a[i - 1];
    let next = a[i + 1];
    if (e === prev && e === next) return '' + e;
    return e;
  }).map(e => typeof e === 'string' ? null : e);
  return _data;
}

var ctx = document.getElementById('chart').getContext('2d');

var gradient1 = ctx.createLinearGradient(0, 0, 0, 400);
gradient1.addColorStop(0, 'rgba(14, 22, 38, 1)');
gradient1.addColorStop(1, 'rgba(1, 103, 147, 0.7)');
/***************/

var datas = [];
datas.push({x: "01-04-2001 10:05:46", y: 175});
datas.push({x: "01-10-2002 10:15:46", y: 140});
datas.push({x: "01-07-2003 11:47:26", y: 98});
datas.push({x: "01-10-2003 01:07:42", y: 130});
datas.push({x: "01-09-2006 06:55:46", y: 164});
datas.push({x: "01-04-2013 10:22:35", y: 178});
datas.push({x: "01-10-2015 10:05:46", y: 118});
datas.push({x: "01-10-2018 10:05:46", y: 158});


var timeFormat = "DD-MM-YYYY HH:MM:SS";

var options = {
  type: 'line',
  data: {
    datasets: [{
      fillColor: gradient1,
      backgroundColor: gradient1,
      borderColor: gradient1,
      fill: 'origin',
      strokeColor: gradient1,
      pointBackgroundColor: "#00b2ff",
      pointRadius: 2,
      pointBorderWidth: 0,
      pointHoverRadius: 3,
      pointHoverBackgroundColor: "rgba(0, 178, 255, 1)",
      data: datas,
      steppedLine: true,
      spanGaps: true
    }, ]
  },
  options: {
    responsive: true,
    maintainAspectRatio: false,
    datasetStrokeWidth: 1,
    pointDotRadius: 3,
    pointDotStrokeWidth: 1,
    pointHitDetectionRadius: 1,
    tooltipFillColor: "rgba(120,0,0,0.8)",
    tooltipFontStyle: "bold",
    animation: false,
    scaleFontColor: "#ffffff",
    scaleFontStyle: "bold",
    scales: {
      xAxes: [{
        type: "time",
        time: {
          format: timeFormat,
          tooltipFormat: 'll',
          min: new Date(2001, 1, 4, 1, 0, 0, 0),
        },
        ticks: {
          maxTicksLimit: 21,
          minRotation: 90,
          fontColor: '#ffffff'
        },

        gridLines: {
          color: "#444444"
        }
      }],
      yAxes: [{
        ticks: {
          fontColor: '#ffffff'
        },
        gridLines: {
          color: "#444444"
        },
      }]
    }
  },
}

var myLineChart = new Chart(ctx, options);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.22.2/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.7.3/Chart.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="chart" width="800" height="400" style="background: #202020"></canvas>
```

Comment: Chart.js is damned. I spent and lose a lot of time on it. You will face bugs after bugs. The docs are very bad, and the coding style very boring. Every plugins are bringing more bugs and memory leaks.  Leave  it, run your own charting plugin with svg/canvas. Avoid d3 too, while d3 is still way better. Also jquery and chart.js can make conflicts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you're looking for `DD-MM-YYYY HH:mm:ss` See [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/format/) for a list of allowable format tokens (chart.js uses the same formats which is specified [here](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/axes/cartesian/time.html)).

MM is for months (as you're using currectly in the `DD-MM-YYYY` section and SS is for fractional seconds. I dont think you are wanting either of those to display the time (could be wrong about that on the fractional seconds but definitely not months being the minutes)

If you're wanting your labels to have the time on them as well then you can use:

```
`type: "time",
time: {
   displayFormats:{ timeFormat },
   min: new Date(2001, 1, 4, 1, 0, 0, 0),
},`
```

Both of these solutions combined yield the following chart:

```
function factorData(data) {
  let _data = data.map((e, i, a) => {
    let prev = a[i - 1];
    let next = a[i + 1];
    if (e === prev && e === next) return '' + e;
    return e;
  }).map(e => typeof e === 'string' ? null : e);
  return _data;
}

var ctx = document.getElementById('chart').getContext('2d');

var gradient1 = ctx.createLinearGradient(0, 0, 0, 400);
gradient1.addColorStop(0, 'rgba(14, 22, 38, 1)');
gradient1.addColorStop(1, 'rgba(1, 103, 147, 0.7)');
/***************/

/* var datas = [];
var labelss = [];
var quantity = 50;
for (var i = 0; i < quantity; i++) {
  var test = Math.floor((Math.random() * 100) + 1);
  datas.push(test);
  labelss.push(i);
} */

var datas = [];
datas.push({x: "01-04-2001 10:05:46", y: 175});
datas.push({x: "01-10-2002 10:15:46", y: 140});
datas.push({x: "01-07-2003 11:47:26", y: 98});
datas.push({x: "01-10-2003 01:07:42", y: 130});
datas.push({x: "01-09-2006 06:55:46", y: 164});
datas.push({x: "01-04-2013 10:22:35", y: 178});
datas.push({x: "01-10-2015 10:05:46", y: 118});
datas.push({x: "01-10-2018 10:05:46", y: 158});


var timeFormat = "DD-MM-YYYY HH:mm:ss";

var options = {
  type: 'line',
  data: {
    //labels: labelss,
    datasets: [{
      fillColor: gradient1,
      backgroundColor: gradient1,
      borderColor: gradient1,
      fill: 'origin',
      strokeColor: gradient1,
      pointBackgroundColor: "#00b2ff",
      pointRadius: 2,
      pointBorderWidth: 0,
      pointHoverRadius: 3,
      pointHoverBackgroundColor: "rgba(0, 178, 255, 1)",
      data: datas,
      steppedLine: true,
      spanGaps: true
    }, ]
  },
  options: {
    responsive: true,
    maintainAspectRatio: false,
    datasetStrokeWidth: 1,
    pointDotRadius: 3,
    pointDotStrokeWidth: 1,
    pointHitDetectionRadius: 1,
    tooltipFillColor: "rgba(120,0,0,0.8)",
    tooltipFontStyle: "bold",
    animation: false,
    scaleFontColor: "#ffffff",
    scaleFontStyle: "bold",
    scales: {
      xAxes: [{
        type: "time",
        time: {
          displayFormats:{ timeFormat },
          min: new Date(2001, 1, 4, 1, 0, 0, 0)
        },
        ticks: {
          maxTicksLimit: 21,
          minRotation: 90,
          fontColor: '#ffffff'
        },

        gridLines: {
          color: "#444444"
        }
      }],
      yAxes: [{
        ticks: {
          fontColor: '#ffffff'
        },
        gridLines: {
          color: "#444444"
        },
      }]
    }
  },
}

var myLineChart = new Chart(ctx, options);
```

Comment: That's what I needed. Thank you!